# My Heroku App stucks at Pending status on GitHub

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

First of all, hello everyone. I created a bot for Telegram that I wrote with node.js. When I want to deploy it on Heroku, it continues to deploy for a very long time (Approximately 20mins and failure). When I want to try the bot on telegram it works fine. But I still see "Pending" text instead of "Success" in the Github Environments section. What can I do? The logs are like this:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  16.14
       engines.npm (package.json):   8.5
       
       Resolving node version 16.14...
       Downloading and installing node 16.14.2...
       Bootstrapping npm 8.5 (replacing 8.5.0)...
       npm 8.5 installed
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       
       added 126 packages, and audited 127 packages in 2s
       
       16 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       found 0 vulnerabilities
       
-----> Build
       Running build
       
       > pokedex-bot-telegram@1.0.0 build
       > node index.js
       
-----> Timed out running buildpack Node.js
Terminated
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: Why is your build trying to run `node index.js`? Do you have a `build` script defined in your `package.json`?

Comment: ​  ​"scripts"​: { 
 ​    ​"start"​: ​"​node index.js​"​, 
 ​    ​"build"​: ​"​node index.js​"​, 
 ​    ​"dev"​: ​"​nodemon index.js​" 
 ​  },

Comment: I have a script like this

Comment: My problem is fixed, thanks for your suggestion  All I had to do was remove the build part

Answer (score 0):

Below is the JSON extracted from the comments from your question. This helps with solving the issue.

```json
{
  ​"scripts"​: {
    ​"start"​: ​"​node index.js​"​, 
    ​"build"​: ​"​node index.js​"​,
    ​"dev"​: ​"​nodemon index.js​"
  }
}
```

---

The solution is to delete the `build` step.

This is because `start` and `build` are doing the exact same things, so there's no point in running it twice.

When you remove the `build` part, and run it again, it should complete everything, without getting stuck on `build`.